# Where to ask questions about reincarnation?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there any Stack Exchange site suitable for asking questions about reincarnation?

Basically I want to ask *“Is there any scientific proof for reincarnation?”* or *“Is there any scientific evidence that reincarnation may be a real phenomenon?”*

Comment: @Snow How "reincarnation" related to "earth being round and the sun being the center of the solar system"? I mean as reincarnation, after we dead, re-birthing again. Do you mean something else?

Comment: I was going to suggest https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/ but it [turns out](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3083/why-was-this-question-deleted-could-it-be-un-deleted/3084#3084) reincarnation questions are not liked there.

Comment: Eh, maybe [philosophy.se](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/)? Not sure about the scientific proof angle of your question and I'm also not a member of that site, but that seems to be the closest place where they _might_ take it. Wouldn't hurt to ask on their [meta](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/) first.

Comment: I asked it from skeptics.se as @JasonBassford suggested. Thanks Jason

Comment: Well, there was the work of [prof. dr. Ian Stevenson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ian_Stevenson). But as I understand it, his research in this particular area does not hold up to scientific standards.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a notable claim, either that it's possible or that it's not, then you could ask on Skeptics.  But you can't just ask "is X true?" questions there; Skeptics is about vetting claims, not answering all questions that people might want to have scrutinized.  Also, as noted in a comment, they [don't welcome religious questions that can't be tested](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3084/14145), so you'd need to be careful in how you frame the question.

Philosophy has [a few questions about reincarnation](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search?q=reincarnation+is%3Aq); you could review those and try to judge whether your question would fit in there.

Reincarnation is part of some religions that have Stack Exchange sites, but it sounds like your goal is to disprove reincarnation, not ask about it in a religious context.  When asking questions on any religion-related site it's best to be respectful of the context; many members of these communities are adherents of those religions, so asking a question that comes across as "how do I prove/disprove one of your core religious tenets from outside of your religion" doesn't tend to go well.

Answer (score 0):

There are sites for both [Hinduism](https://Hinduism.stackexchange.com) and [Buddhism](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com). I don't know what their guidelines are on science based questions, but I'd expect something on the topic would be allowed, although it may require some edits to meet the guidelines.